# Combine custom variables and events in Google Analytics to track marketing campaign effectiveness

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to track the success of marketing campaigns through conversion on a portal. The portal is largely JS based and for right now we can't use URL goal tracking. Instead, I'm planning on using event-based goal conversion that can report all the variables I need. The problem is how do I connect marketing campaigns to the eventual conversion? These campaigns span SEM, email, landing pages, partnerships, etc.

My initial idea was to use a URL param to set a session-level custom variable identifying the marketing campaign that funneled the visitor, and then to compare this to goal conversion. However, I'm not sure custom variables can even be compared to goal conversions in Google Analytics -- and I'm worried that I might be over-thinking this.

I'm worried I'm way over-thinking this. If I create a [custom campaign](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns#customCampaignTracking) using the [URL Builder](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1007028&answer=1033867), will that give me everything I want, allowing me to track campaign conversions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you are over-thinking things. :-)

As long as you properly tag the campaigns using the utm variables in your destination URLs as they show you how to do in URL builder, they should allow you to see your specific goal conversions by source, medium, campaign, etc. in your GA profile. Using the new Multi-Channel funnels features you'll also be able to see how the sources of previous visits influence future conversion behavior as well.

Generate help with campaign conversion tracking here: http://blog.crazyegg.com/2011/12/02/track-conversions-google-analytics-campaigns/

Info on Multi-Channel funnels here: https://www.google.com/analytics/features/multichannel-funnels.html